# Postgres copy table schema is_null constraints not included

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, rdbms, knime

i have a table with the ff columns and constraints :

```
create table newtable(
    id int4 not null primary key,
    lastname varchar(50) not null,  
    firstname varchar(50) not null,
    middlename varchar(50) not null
)
```

I'm developing a workflow script (KNIME) that would test the schema from the source to target.
so i use the ff. code :

```
CREATE TABLE xtable 
AS TABLE newtable;
```

When i checked the is_null constraints, it was set to 'yes' (but in the original table, it was set to 'no'). How can i include the constraints using the above-mentioned code script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can't achieve it with the current approach. The best option I know is the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE xtable (LIKE newtable INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO xtable SELECT * FROM newtable;
```

You can read about this syntax [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: Thanks @ginkul. this is exactly what i need.